# Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: public default void android.content.ServiceConnection.onBindingDied

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

In Android 8.0, the push service appears this log, and then hangs.

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: public default void android.content.ServiceConnection.onBindingDied(android.content.ComponentName)
       at bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.invoke(Unknown Source:20)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
       at $Proxy4.onBindingDied(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1814)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1847)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7380)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

Comment: Did you update compileSdkVersion to 26 and higher? The method was added in API 26.

Comment: Please read [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: Is your app created from Unity? If yes, then this is a bug reported in Unity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451229/1702818